# What's wrong with this Kotlin schedule conditional?

Tags: kotlin, time, conditional-statements

I'm making a schedule app for my high school. I'm trying to practice it in the Kotlin playground online. One of the functions is that it tells you what period it is, but it's not working.

```
    val currentDate = LocalDateTime.now()

    // The year, month, and day are for another part of the app.
    val year = currentDate.year
    val month = currentDate.monthValue
    val day = currentDate.dayOfMonth
    val hour = currentDate.hour
    val minute = currentDate.minute
```

```
val whatPeriod = when {
    hour < 8 || (hour == 7 && minute < 59) -> "Before school"
    (hour == 8 && minute in 0..41) -> "It's period one."
    (hour == 8 && minute in 45..59) || (hour == 9 && minute in 0..26) -> "It's period two."    
    (hour == 9 && minute in 31..59) || (hour == 10 && minute in 0..15) -> "It's period three."
    (hour == 10 && minute in 20..59) || (hour == 11 && minute in 0..1) -> "It's period four."
    (hour == 11 && minute in 6..47) -> "It's period five."
    (hour == 11 && minute in 52..59) || (hour == 12 && minute in 0..33) -> "It's period six."
    (hour == 12 && minute in 38..59) || (hour == 13 && minute in 0..19) -> "It's period seven."
    (hour == 13 && minute in 24..59) || (hour == 14 && minute in 0..5) -> "It's period eight."
    (hour == 14 && minute in 9..59) || (hour == 15 && minute in 0..50) -> "It's period nine."
    (hour == 15 && minute in 54..59) || (hour == 16 && minute in 0..35) -> "It's period ten."
    hour >= 16 && minute >= 35 -> "After school"
    else -> "Between classes"
}


println(whatPeriod)
```

I ran this code at 2:20, so it should say that it's Period 9. Instead, it prints "Between classes".

Comment: It's really hard to guess what could be wrong. Pleas print `hour` and `minute` and you will probably know straight away.

Comment: It works as expected at 2:20pm: https://pl.kotl.in/bCj_ZXVwP

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's some weird start end/times for classes, but aside from that - here is a different way of coding a solution which is more "Kotlin" - you might find it easier to configure the period start/ends

```kotlin
    data class Period(
        val name: String,
        val startTimeInclusive: LocalTime,
        val endTimeExclusive: LocalTime,
    )

    val periodsByStartTime: NavigableMap<LocalTime, Period> = listOf(
        Period("It's period one.", LocalTime.of(8, 0), LocalTime.of(8, 42)),
        Period("It's period two.", LocalTime.of(8, 45), LocalTime.of(9, 27)),
        Period("It's period three.", LocalTime.of(9, 31), LocalTime.of(10, 16)),
        // more here....
    ).map { it.startTimeInclusive to it }.toMap(TreeMap())

    fun findPeriod(now: LocalTime): String {
        val period = periodsByStartTime.floorEntry(now)?.value
        return if (period == null) "Before school."
        else if (now >= LocalTime.of(16, 35)) "After school."
        else if (now < period.endTimeExclusive) period.name
        else "Between classes"
    }
```

Some things to note:

1. Even if other part of your code uses `LocalDateTime` you can obtain `LocalTime` from that easily
2. This solution uses a `NavigableMap` which has a nice feature to find the "proper" Period based on the start time using `floorEntry`,
3. but since the periods don't "touch" you also need to test the end of the period.  I've used an EXCLUSIVE end, so that you can test with `now < period.endTimeExclusive`.  If you didn't use an exclusive boundary, then you could easily get a defect with `now <= period.endTimeInclusive` because you need to think about the seconds/milliseconds part of the time. In your code period one ends after 08:41, so 08:41:00 is in the period, but what about 08:41:01, etc?

Hope this alternate solution is of interest to you.